# Profile dependent web.xml

Tags: maven, tomcat, ssl, config

Im using force ssl configuration on my production server for tomcat. I would like to disable this feature in development and would like to know what my options are. The configuration happens in my web.xml file. I currently build my project using maven so I already have a few profiles where Id prefer to set the settings.

Answer (score 5):

Somewhere in your web.xml you may have the following setting:

```
<transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>
```

If so then, you could use a property place holder for the transport guarantee property, and resource filter it during the build. Replace that line in your web.xml with something like:

```
<transport-guarantee>${transport.guarantee}</transport-guarantee>
```

You can assign the default value which can be "CONFIDENTIAL" to the property ${transport.guarantee} in the pom file or external properties file, and override this in a dev environment by giving a command line argument:

```
mvn clean package -Dtransport.guarantee="NONE"
```

If you are using maven war plugin, resource filtering can be enabled from within the pom file by:

```
      <configuration>
                <webResources>
                    <resource>
                        <filtering>true</filtering>
                        <directory>src/main/webapp</directory>
                        <includes>
                            <include>**/web.xml</include>
                        </includes>
                    </resource>
                </webResources>
                <warSourceDirectory>src/main/webapp</warSourceDirectory>
                <webXml>src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml</webXml>
            </configuration>
```

Finally if you have to make use of your existing profiles then set the value of transport.guarantee based on which profile is active. One way to do this:

```
<profiles>
 <profile>
  <id>development</id>
  <properties>
    <transport.guarantee>NONE</transport.guarantee>
  </properties>
</profile>
<profile>
  <id>production</id>
  <properties>
    <transport.guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport.guarantee>
  </properties>
</profile>
```

You want to set the production profile to active as a default setting. Override and make you development profile active using ~/.m2/settings.xml file.